# Quartz scheduling multiple rest end points

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I am using quartz scheduler along with spring. I need to schedule multiple rest end points at different times. I have created a restclient which is my job. So when the app starts the end points and cron time will be picked up from database or config and multiple triggers with different cron time and different urls need to be created.  What is the best possible way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

*Did not get your question. So, this is based on what I understood.*

> Remember, one trigger can be associated to one job only but multiple
>   triggers can be applied to the same job.

- Having said that, you will have to create a job for each url. So you can execute your restclient for that url based on its schedule adhering to the cron expression.
- If multiple urls share the same schedule(cron pattern), you can make a common job and add these urls inside jobDataMap present inside the common  job. When the job initiates extract urls from the jobDataMap and call rest-client for each url.

Hope this helps !

Comment: there are multiple urls with different cron pattern and I don't want to write a job for each url and pattern

Comment: Then you can create a job whose jobDataMap holds all URLs with the same cron expression. Thus minimum jobs will be required.